# Get inline data from serial

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a method in my `TerminalPanel` class when receiving a serial read:

```
def OnSerialRead(self, event):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    text = event.data
    self.text_ctrl_output.AppendText(text)
    self.GetParent().graphics_panel.get_data(text)
```

Now, inside the `TerminalPanel` class the text comes out perfectly, but in my `GraphicsPanel` class (instantiated with graphics_panel somewhere else) I have this method:

```
def get_data(self, text):
    self.mario = text
    print self.mario
```

The result is that I get this on my terminal:

> 20
>
> 14-1
>
> 1-25
>
> 20:
>
> 19:5
>
> 7 0
>
> 2 2
>
> 393

Whereas in my `TerminalPanel` I get the following:

> 2014-11-25  20:19:57 0 2 2 393

Could you please help me to get my data in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `self.GetParent().graphics_panel.get_data(text)` gets called multiple times and each time the `print self.mario` is printing the text which naturally prints on a new line. You can change it to `sys.stdout.write(self.mario)` which will print to the same line. You have to do an 'import sys', preferably at the top of the file, for this to work.

Alternatively you can do `print self.mario,`. Note the comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: `NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined`

Comment: you have to do an 'import sys', preferably in the top section of your file

Comment: You are welcome, I added an alternate method as well

Comment: Is there any difference? I'm actually interested in using the last 4 values e.g. 2014-11-25 20:19:57 `0 2 2 393`

Comment: No difference, alternate method doesn't need the import of sys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65637/discussion-between-mario-s-e-and-user3885927).