# How to build-up chopped information from serial

Tags: python, wxpython

This is kind of a follow-up question of this one: [Get inline data from serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134603/get-inline-data-from-serial)

Just to make it clear, I have a `TerminalPanel` class which has the `OnSerialRead` method:

```
def OnSerialRead(self, event):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    text = event.data
    self.text_ctrl_output.AppendText(text)
    self.GetParent().graphics_panel.get_data(text)
```

So far so good.  It acquires everything I'm expecting from the serial port (as I see it in my `text_ctrl_outout.AppendText(text)`.

Nonetheless, I want to pass that information, that looks something like this:

> 2014-11-25 20:19:57 0 2 2 393

to my `GraphicsPanel` class through the `get_data` method:

```
def get_data(self, text):
    self.mario = text
    print self.mario
```

My problem is that what I get on my terminal is this:

> ```
> 20
>
> 14-1
>
> 1-25
>
> 20:
>
> 19:5
>
> 7 0
>
> 2 2
>
> 393
> ```

Even though I've been using the accepted solution, it only helps me to *pretty print* it.  I want to be able to use the last four columns (i.e., to remove the timestamp) so I can graph these values.

How can I get them?

Answer (score 0):

If the whole line ends with line break "\n" you need to store your text in buffer (string) until it appears in incoming text. It easier to concat and split it

```
def __init__(self, ... ):
   self.buffer=""

def OnSerialRead(self, event):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    lines = (self.buffer + event.data).split('\n')
    self.buffer= lines[-1]  #anything after last line break store in buffer
    for text in lines[:-1]: #work for 0 or more lines 
        self.text_ctrl_output.AppendText(text)
        columns= text.split()
        data=' '.join( columns[-4:] )
        self.GetParent().graphics_panel.get_data(data)
```

If it is serial communication you might clear the buffer after some time without any read. You simply need to create timer and restart each time in this function.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said and I got this error:  `lines = (self.buffer + event.data).split('\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: @MarioS.E.  Could you determine and say what event.data is? If it is string check that you have `self.buffer=""` or change the name to some other variable.

Comment: I have this:  `event = SerialRxEvent(self.GetId(), text)`, where SerialRxEvent is `class SerialRxEvent(wx.PyCommandEvent):
 """Serial read event."""
 
 def __init__(self, windowID, data):
  wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self, self.eventType, windowID)
  self.data = data
 
 
 eventType = SERIALRX`

Comment: and finally this: `SERIALRX = wx.NewEventType()
EVT_SERIALRX = wx.PyEventBinder(SERIALRX, 0)`

Comment: @MarioS.E. Ah! you make mistake in line 201. It should be "[-1]" without ":".

Comment: got it, but I think I wasn't clear: I want to show everything on the `TerminalPanel` (hence the `self.text_ctrl_output.AppendText(text)`).  That part works just fine.  Now, I want to send to the `GraphicsPanel` (specifically to the `get_data` method) just the last 4 columns (the same line that is showing in `TextPanel`, just without the timestamp)

Comment: Alternatively, send everything to `get_data`, but somehow manage to just grab the last 4 columns

Comment: @MarioS.E. after you have full line simply split it and pass last four elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65700/discussion-between-mario-s-e-and-arpegius).